# How do I determine the "z-index" of a Firemonkey component that I have used SendToBack or BringToFront methods on?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

I have tested putting components on a standard FMX form (TForm) and viewing this form as text.  It seems the IDE is automatically putting the components in the correct rendering order to get the order of components correct.  If I am dynamically creating components and re-ordering them (TRectangle, TEllipse), I'd like to know how to determine their "z-index" for rendering them or recreating them from disk again.  I have looked things like ComponentIndex but this does not change when I apply SendToBack and BringToFront to a component.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After some fiddling and checking the results I have managed to determine that TFMXObject has an Index property. (Thanks to @Tom for pointing this out).   I can use this to determine the "z-index" of a dynamically created component.
**I am using the latest version of RAD Studio.**

```
AComponent := TEllipse.Create(Self);
AComponent.Parent := Self;
AComponent.Position.X := 0;
AComponent.Position.Y := 0;
AComponent.Width := 100;
AComponent.Height := 100;

AComponent.Index := 5; //This is the magic bit
```

Simply storing and setting the Index property after creating the components dynamically restores their proper order on the form or layout.

Comment: You speak about `TComponent` and its `Index` property. But such a property doesn't exist for a `TComponent`. Also, `Parent`, `Position`, `Width` and `Height` are not properties of `TComponent`. They are properties of `TControl`. Playing with the control index at run time soon becomes a viable source of errors. When you assign an index at runtime, all controls (of the same parent) with the same or higher indexes change, and it becomes impossible to keep track of which index refers to which control. Maybe I just don't understand what you are aiming at.

Comment: I'm storing a screen created at runtime in a database, I needed to restore the screen as it was when the user created it, some components were not keeping their "z-index" correctly, after setting Index they were re-created correctly again.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thanks for your observations, I missed where Index was inherited, I've corrected above to TFMXObject, hope it makes sense now. Also I haven't experienced any issues setting the index, seems to work as expected.